# Listen for IFrame height change and ignore if set in '%'

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We are migrating UI from HTML4 from HTML5 where IFrames are continued to be supported to load several types of client applications. Previously, IFrame height was set in '%' in most of the scenarios and rarely in pixels (px). But, HTML5 does not support setting height in '%', hence CSS3 view port units such as 'vh' and 'vw' are used to replace '%' though semantically both are little variant.

But, the problem here is though in my application height of the iFrame is set in 'vh' to achieve the same behavior as before the consuming application still in HTML4 and tries to adjust the height in %. So it does not work. Since IFrame does not support 'resize' event, I would want to listen for the height change of the iFrame so that if height units are '%' I will replace with 'vh' in the parent.

```
$('iframe1').css('height', '90vh'); // earlier it was 90% which does not work in HTML5
```